# How to convert blob to xml type?

Tags: xml, oracle, blob

I want to convert the blob data type to xml data type during the extraction from the database

Below is my database scenario

```
SQL> select * from lmm_schedule_dates
  2  ;

RECID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XMLRECORD
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MM073390000800
32303037333430FD44FE32303037333436FD44FE32303037333533FD44FE32303037333630FD44FE
32303038303032FD44FE32303038303039FD44FE32303038303136FD41
```

In Column XMLRECORD i have blob data type. I want to convert it to xml data type during the extraction from the database.

Below is the query i have tried:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(xmlrecord)) from lmm_schedule_dates;
```

Is there any idea behind this?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle there is XMLType constructor, which can do that convertion:

```
constructor function XMLType(
   xmlData IN blob, csid IN number,
   schema IN varchar2 := NULL,
   validated IN number := 0,
   wellformed IN number := 0)
return self as result deterministic
```

So try to use it like this:

```
select xmltype(xmlrecord,873) from lmm_schedule_dates
```

873 in my example is csid of UTF-8 encoding, you can find particular csid by executing query with corresponding parameter:

```
select nls_charset_id('UTF8') from dual;
```

I think it will help.